# Redirect everything from old domain to new domain

Tags: apache, htaccess, redirects, 301-redirect

I need to (permanent) redirect all of the following:

1. `www.example.com`
2. `www.example.com/folder`
3. `sub.example.com`
4. `sub.example.com/folder`

Basically, all URLs that are reachable without being intended to: `www.new-example.com`, I want to do this within Apache and using the `mod_rewrite` module via the `.htaccess` file.

Answer (score 3):

Put this in your *.htaccess*:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.example\.com[NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

[**Source**](https://mathiasbynens.be/notes/no-www-redirects)

Note that this `.htaccess` should, of course, apply to the old domain. Usually in situations like this, the old domain and the new domain point to the same server though, and so get the same `.htaccess`.

Answer (score 2):

Use a 301 redirect in your *.htaccess* file at the old domain:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.new-example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 1):

It would be better to redirect (forward) your domain at your registrar and forward the old domain which includes all sub domains to the new domain. This way your server is not handling all the requests which takes up resources.

Answer (score 0):

To redirect all files on your domain use this in your *.htaccess* file if you are on a UNIX web server:

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/(.*)$ http://www.new-example.com/$1
```

Comment: `RedirectMatch` is a mod_alias directive, not mod_rewrite. (If you were going to use mod_alias then the simpler `Redirect` directive would be preferable in this situation, for example: `Redirect 301 / http://www.new-example.com/`)